# Looking for a zip/unzip dll tool

Tags: open-source, library, software-development

I am looking for a specific programming tool dealing with zip files. I have been using the old LHA32 dll for some time and, while reliable, is aging and I would like to use the zip file format instead of lzh. The nicest thing lha32 does is display progress bars while zipping and unzipping. I would like to find an equivalent zip program or dll I can use from within another program that also displays progress bars but uses the zip format. I am not looking for a stand-alone archiving tool like 7zip, but something that can be used from within another program. I am using a dialect of Basic but can call standard C dll functions. Thank you.